# how can I access typescript class public property at run time (debugging)? only the constructor and functions are accessible

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am implementing a DI container for my framework in typescript, and want to know my class constructor parameters and properties for instantiating. Here is an example:

```
interface IDriver 
{
    Drive(): void
}

class DriverA implements IDriver 
{
    public Tickets: Array<Ticket>;
    public Name: String;

    public Drive() {
        //Driving...
    }
}
```

I am passing the interface name IDriver as string (because I was not able to pass the interface as a parameter) and concrete class DriverA to my registration routine. Latter in resolving state, to instantiate DriverA, I got the constructor and the Drive method, but I can't find the properties such as Tickets and Name. How can I access those properties? is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Properties are only available if you initialize them e.g:

```
class DriverA 
{
    public Tickets = [];
    public Name = "";

    public Drive() {
        //Driving...
    }
}
```

will generate :

```
var DriverA = (function () {
    function DriverA() {
        this.Tickets = [];
        this.Name = "";
    }
    DriverA.prototype.Drive = function () {
        //Driving...
    };
    return DriverA;
})();
```

Notice `this.Tickets`. PS: they only get added after the constructor is called. i.e `new DriverA()`

Comment: Thank you Basarat. What a limitation though.